# How do I make the `std::ios_base::copyfmt_event` happen in my tests?

Tags: c++, testing, iostream

I wrote a set of functions to print out an address in my [libaddr](https://github.com/m2osw/libaddr) library (see [addr.h header](https://github.com/m2osw/libaddr/blob/main/libaddr/addr.h)).

I am easily able to test the `erase_event` by changing one of my format flags:

```
std::cout << addr::setaddrsep("\n") << addresses;
```

I do not care about the `imbue_event` (the locale has no effect on IP addresses).

What I'm wondering is how to generate a `copyfmt_event`. When does that happen? Since it is expected to duplicate my structure, I need to make sure that part works as expected (no double `delete`, no leaks, proper copy).

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/event

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/copyfmt `std::ofstream out;
 
    out.copyfmt(std::cout);` no?

Comment: @KamilCuk Oooh! That works. One click away I guess. I just pretty much never use that function. Now I've 100% coverage of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/copyfmt :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
 
int main()
{
    std::ofstream out;
 
    out.copyfmt(std::cout); // copy everything except rdstate and rdbuf
    out.clear(std::cout.rdstate()); // copy rdstate
    out.basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf()); // share the buffer
 
    out << "Hello, world\n";
}
```